# How do I simulate negative binomial random variable in R without using the already created functions?

Tags: r

I have a code that I'm working on that is supposed to simulate a negative binomial random variable. I know that there are already functions in R that can do this sort of thing, but I can't use those and need to use a `while` loop or something similar.

I have that the probability it will rain on a certain day is 10%, and I need to simulate selecting random days until 5 rainy days are selected. I am supposed to return how many days it took until I have 5 rainy days.

I have the following code, which works for simulating the number of days it takes until I get one day of rain, but I don't know how I should adjust this. My initial thought was that I would change the `num.days = 1` to `num.days = 5`, but that would just change the point where the iteration begins in the `while` loop, wouldn't it?

What do I need to add in the code in order to get the number of days it took until there were 5 rainy days?

```
current.day = sample(c("R","NR"),1,prob = c(0.10,0.90))
num.days = 1
while(current.day != "R"){
  current.day = sample(c("R","NR"),1,prob = c(0.10,0.90))
  num.days = num.days+1
}
num.days
all.days = sapply(1:20000,function(i){
  current.day = sample(c("R","NR"),1,prob = c(0.10,0.90))
  num.days = 1
  while(current.day != "R"){
    current.day = sample(c("R","NR"),1,prob = c(0.10,0.90))
    num.days = num.days+1
  }
  return(num.days)
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Is this about how to sample from a NB distribution without using `stats::rnbinom`? Or are you asking how to estimate the parameters of a NB distribution? In case of the former, there are different ways to generate NB samples. For example, you could use [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling); or make use of the fact that the NB dist can be written as Poisson distribution, where the mean is Gamma distributed.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes, I am trying to replicate what that function does. I'm not particularly well-versed in r, and this example comes from a discussion I had in my university class. According to a peer this can/should (due to the scope of my class) just using while loops... In this code I posted I get the amount of days before the first day of rain, but I want to get the total amount of days before I get 5 days of rain. For example, say I need go through 30 days before I get 5 days of rain. I don't know how to implement this into my code

Comment: Well, I've given you two hints how you can implement sampling from an NB distribution; both are easy to implement. Not sure what this has to do with a `while` loop; sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: @a.silke I think maybe you want `while (num.days < 5) ...` to run the loop until 5 "R" days are sampled.